# What is the path you pass to npm http-server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, httpserver

I'm using a mac and I made a directory on my desktop called "reg" with an index.html in it and then tried running `http-server "Desktop/reg/" but it didn't work. I tried adding in my absolute path like`"/Users/johndoe/Desktop/reg/"` and it doesn't work either. What am I doing wrong that it keeps giving me 404?

Comment: try list all your directory first by ls and see if reg is there or not

Answer (score 0):

You just need to run `http-server` in your Desktop folder.

`cd ~/Desktop
http-server reg`